# Android: Share Menu, My menu inflater cannot Resolve my resource

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add a share menu to my app that sends text from textview 2 to another app I.E KiK but currently i cannot get it to identify the Resource file as the menu heres my code:

```
public class ME extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

       getMenuInflater().inflate(android.R.menu.main, menu);
       MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");
        mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

The `getMenuInflater().inflate(android.R.menu.main, menu);` is the problem

And my XML Resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <TextView
        android:="@+id/TextView 1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >
     </TextView>

     <TextView
        android:="@+id/TextView 2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >
     </TextView>

     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
        <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:actionProviderClass= "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
   </menu>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change `android.R.menu.main` to `R.menu.main`

Comment: That Still gives me an error because it then cannot identify menu

Comment: Read up on how to [make a menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). Menu xmls are part of the `menu` folder and they are **not** part of an Activity layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
          android:actionProviderClass= "android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
           />
   </menu>
```

Should be put in a seperate xml file in the menu folder (say main.xml).

And,

`getMenuInflater().inflate(android.R.menu.main, menu);`

should be corrected as

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

Comment: No share.xml should be in a folder called menu. You have put it in the layout folder.